# What are the system requirements for Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, system-requirements

I have Lucid running pretty stable out of box on my dual core 3.0Ghz Pentium with 1GB of ram, so would it be pushing it to throw Gnome 3 on there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have tried searching the Gnome.org web site to find an answer. I have tried a web search based on Gnome 3 requirements. I am surprised at the number of times that this or a similar question has been asked on the forums of various Linux distributions  and the same answer is always given. It is a quote from this page:

[Gnome Myths](http://live.gnome.org/GNOME3Myths)

> It is our primary focus to build a modern operating environment,
> platform, and user experience. It doesn't make sense to target the
> hardware of the past. GNOME Shell uses relatively primitive 3D
> capabilities that have been available from essentially all computing
> devices made in the last four or five years. This includes most
> desktop and laptop computers, mobile devices, phones, tablets, and
> netbooks. Where there are exceptions, largely, there are bugs we can
> and should fix.
>
> So, the official plan is that people can still use the GNOME 2 shell
> with GNOME 3 applications and libraries, if necessary, but this is a
> transitional state, and to get the GNOME 3 experience, your computer
> needs hardware acceleration.

So, the answer from the official source is "you need a computer built in the last 4 to 5 years and to get the Gnome 3 experience you need hardware acceleration." And that means a video card capable of doing accelerated graphics.

Personally, I would not call that quote a proper specification of hardware requirements for running Gnome 3. But there you are.

In your case if you do not intend to fit a video adapter then you will not be running gnome shell or any other user interface. And that is fine. So, the "hardware acceleration" requirement is not appropriate.

My machine is four years old and it has a slightly lower specification than your machine and it is running Gnome 3 with Ubuntu Unity both in 11.10 and 12.04 development branch in a more than adequate way.

But for completeness of answer I repeat my comment that the video card is the key component for running the User Interface on a Gnome 3 desktop environment be it Unity, or Gnome 3 shell. And a video card with anything less 512GB memory will give a disappointing performance unless used in fall-back mode.

Update:

I have found the release notes for 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot which is the first Ubuntu to be built on the Gnome 3 desktop environment.

[11.10 system requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/ReleaseNotes#System_Requirements)

The minimum memory for the desktop is 384MB. But this comment might be more applicable for you:

> The minimum memory requirement for Ubuntu Server 11.10 is 128 MB of
> memory.

Again for completeness I add this link:

[Unity Graphics requirements](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements)

If the video card is capable of doing this it is capable of running Unity and I would guess that it is also capable of running Gnome 3 shell:

**OpenGL Version required by Unity**

Unity requires OpenGL 1.4 of higher. Because of the decoupling between Opengl versions and the first implementation of new extensions by hardware vendors, just having OpenGL 1.4 is not enough. The system must also have support for a number of OpenGL extensions.

> **OpenGL Extensions required**
>
> Framebuffer Object
>
> Rectangle Textures
>
> Non power of 2 textures
>
> Vertex programs
>
> Fragment programs
>
> buffer objects
>
> GLSL shader support
>
> (Optional) **Other requirements**
>
> Minimum 128MB of video
>
> memory Minimum texture width/height 2048
>
> Enough > registers for vertex and fragment shaders programs

Regards.

Comment: I guess the question becomes, "am I willing to invest $50-80 in a PCI-E 1x card?" The PC has a riser card, but it only has a 1x slot. I don't know how good the integrated graphics is, but I think I'll stick with gnome2. All of my company workstations will probably be around the $500 mark which will give some leeway for hardware acceleration (maybe an APU?).

Comment: I suppose you mean 512MB instead of 512GB of video memory.

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

- the Gnome Shell [version available for 10.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gnome-shell) is 2.28, is that what you are looking for?
- the [documentation](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/FAQ#What_led_to_the_decision_to_make_3D_acceleration_a_requirement_for_GNOME_Shell.3F) says it requires *3D acceleration*. You should check if that works properly on your computer.

There might significant changes on user experience between that version and the latest one (3.2 or something like that). I don't know any backports of Gnome Shell 3.2 for lucid.

Comment: I've read somewhere there is a version available from an external repository. The 3D acceleration will work with this system, but on all the other distros I have tried with Gnome 3 it was slow and laggy (except Fedora 15).

Comment: @Romoku I am using Gnome Shell in my laptop (with a ATI shared memory video card) and it runs normally. But I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 so it is running the 3.2

Answer (score 0):

The absolute simplest answer:
Run 12.04 LTS beta live and find out if the new UI tweaks will hurt you.  It's not a perfect solution, but it's a lot easier than parsing requirements for days.

It's not exactly just Gnome 3, but unity AFAIK is based on Gnome 3.  If you can run one well from live, you should be able to run the other.