# Force Gnome 3 to work

Tags: gnome

I have Ubuntu 12.10 on dual-boot with windows XP.

My PC specifications are AMD Sempron 2800+ 1,6GHz with 512 MB ram and ATI Radeon 9250 graphic card with 128 MB memory.

As Unity works slow and I don't like it's look, I installed `gnome-shell`.
But as you know, Gnome 3 won't work on it. But gnome classic without effects works great.

Thing is, when I turn off windows (by holding the power button or pressing restart button) my resolution on Linux is changed to 1024x768, and I can only change it by turning off the PC and turning off it's power source.

But it is not the problem.
The problem is that it runs Gnome 3 after one restart, it also runs better than Unity.

My question is: Can I somehow force gnome 3 to work always and disable some of it's effects so it can run better?

Comment: I am actually unsure whether your computer is capable of running it. Please check this question: [What are the minimum requirements for Gnome 3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/99005/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-gnome-3)

Answer (score -2):

I was 100% sure it can't, but after force restart from windows it was working... ofcoarse on low resolution and slow but still faster than unity.